# Dashed arrow in state diagram in uml

Tags: uml, state, diagram

what does a dashed arrow mean in state diagram of UML?
between states there is an arrow with a label of the event but there is also a dashed arrow between the same states without any label and in a different direction.what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Hi a dashed arrow represents dependency eg if arrow was from classJ to classI you would say that classJ objects depends on classI object

Answer (score 0):

It is the dependency relationship. It means that the pointing class needs the pointed class for work. For example, uses that class for local variables, of functional parameters. the main question you should set to yourself, is here:  If something changes in B public attributes, may I need to change A code?

But not they are not associated in the sense, that you can't say that an instance or class A have some instances of class B associated. I.e. they can't be references from A to B, let alone set as attribute or counted by some method.

It is not a standard element of State machine diagram, though.